# True/false :Is $\Gamma(h) $ closed in $\mathbb{R}^2?$

Tags: general-topology

Let $h :  \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be  a  continious  function.Define $\Gamma(h) =\{ (a,b) \in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}  : b=h(a)\}$

**My question**:  Is $\Gamma(h) $ closed   in $\mathbb{R}^2?$

**My attempt** : I think **No**  .Take $r: \mathbb{R}^2  \to \mathbb{R} $ and  defined by  $$r(a,b)=b-h(a)$$

since $ b-h(a)=0  \implies (a,b)= r^{-1}(\{0\})$

Thus $\Gamma(h) =r^{-1}(\{0\})$

$(a,b)$  is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$

This implies $\Gamma(h)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: @Yorch i edited

Comment: Where you write $b-h(a)=0\Rightarrow (a,b)=r^{-1}(\{0\})$, you should have $b-h(a)=0\Rightarrow (a,b)\in r^{-1}(\{0\})$. I think this is what leads to the statement "$(a,b)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$", which doesn't really make sense since $(a,b)$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and not a subset.

Comment: You should have written $\{(a, b)\}$ rather than $(a, b)$ and $\{(a, b)\}$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$ for any $a$ and $b$. Simple sketching of functions like $x \mapsto 1$ or $x \mapsto 2x$ should have convinced you that the graph of a continuous function is likely to be closed.

Comment: You also can prove directly using the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition that $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \Gamma(h)$ is open in $\Bbb R^2$ when $h$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have  $\Gamma(h)$ is the preimage of $\{0\}$ under the continuous map $r:\mathbb R\times \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by $r(a,b) = b - h(a)$. Since $\{0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb R$ we conclude $\Gamma(h)$ is closed in $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$, as desired.

If $\{0\}$ was open then we could conclude that $\Gamma(h)$ is open, but $\{0\}$ is not open .